# JQuery .Load not loading css

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, load

I'm starting a web site develop using `PHP`, [`jQuery EasyUI`](http://www.jeasyui.com/),  AJAX, and CSS.

On my first try using jeasyui's tabs everything was fine since all is included within main html..

Here you can see the code extracted from jQuery EasyUI tutorial

```
<body>  
<h2>Nested Tabs</h2>  
<div class="demo-info">  
    <div class="demo-tip icon-tip"></div>  
    <div>The tab panel can contain sub tabs or other components.</div>  
</div>  
<div style="margin:10px 0;"></div>  
<div class="easyui-tabs" data-options="tools:'#tab-tools'" style="width:700px;height:250px">  
    <div title="Sub Tabs" style="padding:10px;">  
        <div class="easyui-tabs" data-options="fit:true,plain:true">  
            <div title="Title1" style="padding:10px;">Content 1</div>  
            <div title="Title2" style="padding:10px;">Content 2</div>  
            <div title="Title3" style="padding:10px;">Content 3</div>  
        </div>  
    </div>
```

As you can see everything works fine since it's all included on same html...

Now I'm trying to get things divided in differents files to get everything more organized ... (here you can see index.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  
    ref="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/themes/default/easyui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/themes/icon.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/jquery.easyui.min.js">  
</script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/datagrid-detailview.js"> 
</script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="connections.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="codigo.js"></script>   

    <script language="javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){

       $("#linkajax").click(function(evento){

          evento.preventDefault();
          //$(document).getElementById('resultado').innerHTML='sales.html'; 

          $("#resultado").load("sales.html");

       });
    })
    </script>   
    </head>

<body >
<div id="main" class="easyui-tabs" style="border:0;width:auto;height:700px;">
    <div title="Tab 1" iconCls="icon-reload" closable="false" onClick="listTab1()" 
style="padding:10px;">
        Tab 1
                    <table id="tab1_table" style="width:900px;height:650px"></table>
    </div>
            <div id="resultado" title="Tickets" iconCls="icon-reload" closable="false" style="  
padding:10px;">
                <a href="#" id="linkajax">Click</a>

    </div>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

here... sales.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"   
href="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/themes/default/easyui.css">
<html>
<head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
href="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/themes/default/easyui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/themes/icon.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js">  
</script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/jquery.easyui.min.js">  
</script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/datagrid-detailview.js">
</script>


</head>
<body >

    <div id="main2" class="easyui-tabs" style="border:0;width:auto;height:700px;">
    <div title="Tab 1" iconCls="icon-reload" closable="false" style="padding:10px;">
        Tab 1
    </div>
            <div title="Tickets" iconCls="icon-reload" closable="false" style=" padding:10px;">
                    Tab 2
    </div>


</div>


</body>
```

here.. the result

[Result](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6lpgnzpodbqj54l/tab.png)

Here you can see that nested tab has no css !...

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Move the link tag inside the head.

Comment: I dont understand what you said about moving link tag inside the head...

Comment: in sales.html, I think  you can also leave only the div with the content in there, have you tried like that?

Comment: Yes It was the first try... only container div... but same result.

Answer (score 0):

Rename sales.html to sales.php and then call jQuery like this.

```
<script language="javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

   $("#linkajax").click(function(evento){

      evento.preventDefault();
      //$(document).getElementById('resultado').innerHTML='sales.html'; 

      $("#resultado").load("sales.php");

   });
})
</script>
```

You also do 'echo' your all code in sales.php.

Hope it helps to you.

Comment: Nop.. just the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether my experience could help, however, I've encountered similar problem and fixed it.

I was using a easyui panel to load different contents according to user selections.  At first, I used

```
$('#panel').load('user_selection.html')
```

to load different contents.  But the contents were displayed without easyui effect.

Then I changed to

```
$('#panel').panel('refresh','user_selection.html')
```

and it then works fine.

Hope this can help.

The reason, IMHO, was easyui's panel->refresh function can fire some easyui script to render the newly loaded contents while the jquery's load() function can not.